# Regexp to match text with optional text in parenthesis

Tags: regex, r

Given the following vector of strings `x`

```
x <- c("hello", "foo_bar", "blah_blub_(bleep)", "blah_(xyz)", "xyz(_$_)")
```

I am looking for a regexp to extract everything before the optional parenthesis (and its content). So the final result for the above vector should be:

```
c("hello", "foo_bar", "blah_blub", "blah", "xyz")
```

I came up with the following regexp which, however, does not work (why?):

```
R> sub("^(.*)[_?\\(.*\\)]?$", \\1, x)
[1] "hello" "foo_bar" "blah_blub_(bleep)" "blah_(xyz)" "xyz(_$_)"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can match the pattern of zero or more `_` followed by `(` followed by one more characters until the end of the string and replace it with `''`.

```
sub('_*\\(.*$', '', x)
#[1] "hello"     "foo_bar"   "blah_blub" "blah"      "xyz"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The negation (removing instead of selecting) works fine here. :)